# Wrap/Convert json object into array of objects MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column named data and I have to update its content from something like `{}` to `[{}]` for each record in table ***A***, I tried to use **JSON_ARRAY()** but it gives me a quoted

```json
["{\"something\": \"true\"}"]
```

but I'd like to have something like

```json
[{ "something": "true" }]
```

How I do it now?

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(data) FROM A;
```

How should I update it either using `JSON_SET()` or `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 2):

### **Try using**

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_AGG(JSON_OBJECT(data)) from A;
```

Comment: This will combine all the rows into a single array.

Comment: Yes it does. This isn't what I was looking for but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a path to get the data as JSON, rather than referring to the column by itself. The path `$` means the top-level object.

```
update A 
SET data = CASE
    WHEN data IS NULL THEN '[]' -- NULL becomes empty array
    WHEN LEFT(data, 1) = '[' THEN data -- leave existing array alone
    ELSE JSON_ARRAY(data->"$") -- put object inside array
END
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pKSS9vgSmsSLn5yiZFkiDc/4)

Comment: Great, how can I apply it using a UPDATE?

UPDATE A SET data=JSON_ARRAY(data->"$") WHERE data IS NOT NULL

Comment: That should work. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pKSS9vgSmsSLn5yiZFkiDc/1

Comment: Great answer. How can I add another condition to prevent running it twice? Like if data is alreay an array?

Comment: You can use a string function like `and LEFT(data, 1) != '['`

Comment: I missed to ask if the column is null is it possible to create an empty array for that? I used 

UPDATE cpdc SET cpdcFormData = JSON_ARRAY() WHERE cpdcFormData IS NULL

But didn't work.

Comment: Also when I want to revert it back using

UPDATE cpdc SET cpdcFormData =cpdcFormData->"$" WHERE LEFT(cpdcFormData, 1) != '['

it doesnt work i think i'm missing a point here.

Comment: Yes, all these things are possible. You can use `IF(data IS NULL, ...)` to get different values depending on this.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using the JSON datatype in the first place. It's annoyingly complicated and non-relational. You should normalize your tables.

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pKSS9vgSmsSLn5yiZFkiDc/3